# How do I add an image icon for custom button in outlook

Tags: c#, outlook, add-in, ribbon-control

I have a custom button in outlook and I have to add image icon for the same button.

Ribbon XML is:

```xml
<button id="GoToAppConfiguration" 
    label="Application Configuration" 
    getImage="GetCustomImage" 
    onAction="GoToAppConfigurationClicked" 
    size="normal" />
```

I want to  write ribbon callback method but how do I write the same and how do I use an image stored in a Resource folder under the Addin project.

Comment: <button id="GoToAppConfiguration" label="Application Configuration" getImage="GetCustomImage" onAction="GoToAppConfigurationClicked" size="normal" />

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You just need to return a [`Bitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx) from `GetCustomImage`. Here is a c# example, assuming you have added the BMP to your [Project Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

```cs
public Bitmap GetCustomImage(Office.IRibbonControl control)
{
    return Properties.Resources.btnAppConfiguration_Image; // resource Bitmap
}
```

Comment: Doesn't the resource manager already give a copy of the image? It works fine if you specify Image instead of Bitmap

Comment: @drake7707 - good catch! I edited the answer for simplicity and removed the unnecessary `Bitmap` instance creation. It appears you can return either `Image` or `Bitmap` for the `getImage` signature - [`IPictureDisp GetImage(IRibbonControl control)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523%28v=office.12%29.aspx). Outlook must handle the translation from `Image` to `IPictureDisp` internally. [`PictureDispConverter` is not required for Ribbon XML customizations](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16148015/175679).

Comment: @SliverNinja Do you have a link which shows all of the callback definitions for Ribbon XML?

Comment: I found it.. Scroll down towards the bottom to table 4. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523.aspx

Comment: In order to make it, I had to add the method into the Ribbon class