# Icon set on an Outlook folder with MAPIFolder.SetCustomIcon does not scale properly on high DPI screen

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, scaling, windows-11

I am trying to set an icon to a folder from VSTO Outlook add-in using approach similar to what described here:
[How to programmatically set a custom icon on an Outlook search folder? (i.e. Outlook Folder SetCustomIcon)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16114566/how-to-programmatically-set-a-custom-icon-on-an-outlook-search-folder-i-e-out)

It is working, but fail in Outlook365/Windows11 setup with high-DPI screen. With scaling set to 250% icon of any size for some reason takes only top-left part and looks like this:

[image]

And when I drag Outlook window on external display with 125% scale it becomes this:

[image]

On 100% screen same approach working without issues.

Is it Outlook bug or there is a way to make it respect DPI settings?

In Windows10/Outlook 365 16.0.15601.20148 32-bit it is working even with 200% scaling, but only if one monitor is present in the system.

Comment: It is not clear when and where you run the code for setting up an icon for the folder.

Comment: But it sounds like a product issue, so I'd suggest opening a support case with MS instead.

Comment: Will try to open ticket. Thanks. I am using this in Outlook VSTO add-in.

Comment: It doesn't matter what kind of add-in you are developing, I've asked about the time when the icon is set in the code - startup, shutdown event handlers and etc. Don't forget to update the post if you receive any meaningful explanation from MS.